# How to undo a migration using Flyway?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, migration, flyway

I am working on a Spring project and I have FlyWay as a dependency to manage my migrations, I made a mistake on the SQL command. When I ran the project I got an error showing a problem with the script, a silly mistake that was easy to fix, I misspelled a column name. However, the undo command from the flyway is not working.

I was trying to undo a migration using FlyWay and I follow the tutorial from FlyWay documentation: [link-flyway](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#undo-migrations)

##### However, I got this output:

```bash
C:\Users\leonardo.freitas\Documents\workspace\api>C:\Users\leonardo.freitas\Documents\workspace\flyway-9.8.1\flyway undo
A new version of Flyway is available
Upgrade to Flyway 9.8.2: https://rd.gt/2X0gakb
ERROR: The command 'undo' was not recognized. Make sure you have added 'flyway-proprietary' as a dependency.
Caused by: No command extension found to handle command: undo
```

##### That's my migration history:

```bash
C:\Users\leonardo.freitas\Documents\workspace\api>C:\Users\leonardo.freitas\Documents\workspace\flyway-9.8.1\flyway info
A new version of Flyway is available
Upgrade to Flyway 9.8.2: https://rd.gt/2X0gakb
Flyway Community Edition 9.8.1 by Redgate
See what's new here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#9.8.1

ERROR: Skipping filesystem location: sql (not found)
Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/volimed (MySQL 8.0)
Schema version: 5

+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+
| Category  | Version | Description                            | Type | Installed On        | State           | Undoable |

C:\Users\leonardo.freitas\Documents\workspace\api>C:\Users\leonardo.freitas\Documents\workspace\flyway-9.8.1\flyway info 
A new version of Flyway is available
Upgrade to Flyway 9.8.2: https://rd.gt/2X0gakb
Flyway Community Edition 9.8.1 by Redgate                                           
See what's new here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#9.8.1

ERROR: Skipping filesystem location: sql (not found)
Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/volimed (MySQL 8.0)
Schema version: 5                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                          
+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+
| Category  | Version | Description                            | Type | Installed On        | State           | Undoable |
+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+
| Versioned | 1       | create-table-medicos                   | SQL  | 2022-11-19 03:12:19 | Future          | No       |
| Versioned | 2       | alter-table-medicos-add-telefone       | SQL  | 2022-11-19 13:32:45 | Future          | No       |
| Versioned | 3       | create-table-pacientes                 | SQL  | 2022-11-19 13:46:17 | Future          | No       |
| Versioned | 4       | alter-table-medicos-add-column-active  | SQL  | 2022-11-19 15:28:46 | Future          | No       |
| Versioned | 5       | alter-table-paciente-add-column-active | SQL  | 2022-11-19 15:45:28 | Failed (Future) | No       |
+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+
```

##### And I want to redu the last migration.

Comment: I found conflicting information on the Redgate site about which edition supports the undo command. One page says it is supported in Flyway for Teams, another page says it is supported in Flyway Enterprise. Either way, it seems it does not work in Flyway Community Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Undo command is supported in both the [Teams and Enterprise edition](https://www.red-gate.com/products/flyway/editions) . Flyway Enterprise is the only version with auto generation of Undo scripts though. Bill, could you point me towards where the information is conflicting?

Comment: I am using the community version

Comment: The undo command only works if you've created an undo script for the corresponding (forward) migration script, so wouldn't have helped you in this instance. Have you tried fixing the script and rerunning the migration? You may have to run "flyway repair" before flyway lets you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I find out a way to resolve this problem, I went to the FlyWay table and deleted the last row, when I ran the project the FlyWay applied the migration again.